# Не могу пройти авторизацию в Internet Explorer ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookie, авторизация, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2015

История в следующем:
 Разработал я ASP.NET MVC проект в Visual Studio 2015. Перед публикацией приложения на IIS решил протестировать:

1. Запустил проект через VS2015 в Internet Explorer
2. Попал на страницу ввода логина и пароля
3. Ввожу логин и пароль, проверка проходит и я вхожу в систему..
4. Дальше занимаюсь просмотром проекта

Все было бы хорошо если бы одно **но**.
Опубликовал приложение на IIS. Открываю IE, перехожу по ссылке, пытаюсь пройти авторизацию, нажимаю кнопку *"Войти"*, а у меня просто как будто обновилась страница и я заново пытаюсь сделать тоже самое, и все также не получается пройти авторизацию.

Разрабатывая проект, я запускал его под Google Chrome. Проблема возникает если пытаться войти через IE.

Как мне побороть данную проблему??

P.S. В консоли браузера никаких сообщений об ошибке не обнаружил.

Comment: Какая версия IE и какой тип аутентификации вы используете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Было следующее: я публиковал на сервер который имеет адресном имени знак "_". Например test.site_test.ru.
https://www.divandesign.ru/blog/2009/march/do_main - подробнее про знак "_" в доменном имени здесь.